# ServerSocket throws InvalidArgumentException, but docs don't specify why. Why?

Tags: c++, serversocket, poco-libraries

I'm using Poco to create a webserver. I ran into an error with the ServerSocket library. Here's the minimum code to reproduce the error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Poco/Net/ServerSocket.h"
#include "Poco/Net/StreamSocket.h"
#include "Poco/Net/SocketAddress.h"
#define PORT (unsigned short) 3000
int main()
{
    Poco::Net::ServerSocket x;
    x.bind(PORT);
    Poco::Net::StreamSocket conn;
    Poco::Net::SocketAddress clientAddr;
    try {
        conn = x.acceptConnection(clientAddr);
    }
    catch (Poco::InvalidArgumentException e) {
        printf("Oh no! %s\n", e.displayText().c_str());
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Huzzah!");
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to look at [the docs] (https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.ServerSocket.html#25093) to understand the error, but it doesn't even list this function as throwing this error. I've also tried the parameterless version of the function, and it still throws this exception, (which indicates to me it's not the function but a sub function throwing the error). Why? and how can I fix it, or work around it?

Comment: Unrelated but change `catch (Poco::InvalidArgumentException e) {` to `catch (const Poco::InvalidArgumentException& e) {`

Comment: *Why? and how can I fix it, or work around it?* -- Doesn't POCO come with full source code?  Why not debug into that function and see which line throws the exception?

Comment: You bind the socket, but don't seem to ever put it in listen-mode. Server's typically bind + listen, the loop on accept. You're binding, never listening, then accept'ing which is invalid because you never listened. (my ex-wife constantly accused me of that, so small world).

Comment: Why haven't you posted the error message here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As WhozCraig said, the problem was not putting it in listening state. The code should be

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Poco/Net/ServerSocket.h"
#include "Poco/Net/StreamSocket.h"
#include "Poco/Net/SocketAddress.h"
#define PORT (unsigned short) 3000
int main()
{
    Poco::Net::ServerSocket x;
    x.bind(PORT);
    x.listen(1); // or number of acceptable connections
    Poco::Net::StreamSocket conn;
    Poco::Net::SocketAddress clientAddr;
    try {
        conn = x.acceptConnection(clientAddr);
    }
    catch (const Poco::InvalidArgumentException& e) {
        printf("Oh no! %s\n", e.displayText().c_str());
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Huzzah!");
    return 0;
}
```